# как написать js функцию?

Tags: javascript, функции

как написать функцию(a) на js, которая при таком вызове: `a(1)(2)(3)` будет перемножать все числа в выведет 6? Буду благодарен.

Comment: https://javascript.info/currying-partials

Comment: Чтобы так сделать надо чтобы функция возвращала функцию. Ну и собственно, надо проверять переданы ли параметры или нет, если нет, то возвращать значение какое-то

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function foo(n) {
  function bar(arg) {
    n *= arg;
    return bar;
  }
  
  bar.toString = function() {
    return n;
  }
  
  return bar;
}

console.log(foo(1));
console.log(foo(1)(2)(3));
console.log(foo(1)(2)(3)(4));
```

Comment: При запуске в Node.js все три раза выдаётся `[Function: bar] { toString: [Function (anonymous)] }`

Comment: При запуске в консоли Хрома: `ƒ 1 ƒ 6 ƒ 24`.

Comment: @vsemozhebuty, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34865971/javascript-tostring-seems-not-to-be-called-automatically-in-nodejs

Comment: Я просто к тому, что такое хитрое решение не универсально и имеет побочные эффекты)